# Как склонять фамилию Кафтанатий?

Tags: ономастика, склонение-фамилий

..................................................................................

Answer (score 2):

Русские и иноязычные фамилии, оканчивающиеся на согласный звук, склоняются, если относятся к мужчинам, и не склоняются, если относятся к женщинам. Таким образом склоняется и фамилия Кафтанатий.

Буква Й обозначает согласный непарный звук. До сер. XIX в. буква называлась «и с краткой» (кратка — надстрочный знак) по образцу i «и с точкой», позже переименована в «и краткое».

Фамилия изменяется по 2-му склонению как существительное м. рода, одушевлённое.